# What is the value of $a+b+c$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, self-learning

> What is the value of $a+b+c$?
>
> if $$a^4+b^4+c^4=32$$
> $$a^5+b^5+c^5=186$$
> $$a^6+b^6+c^6=803$$

How to approach this kind of problem. Any help.

**UPDATE:** Thank you all for answers. Now I realize there is no integer solution. But is there any real number solution? I am curious to know.

Comment: Are you looking for integer solutions?

Comment: @mfl: yes.Integer solution..

Comment: See [Newton's identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_identities) and [Newton-Girard formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Newton-GirardFormulas.html).

Comment: You should post a new question if you have another question.

Answer (score 7):

If $x$ is an integer then $x^4$ and $x^6$ have the same parity. Therefore $a^4+b^4+c^4$ and $a^6+b^6+c^6$ are either both odd or both even.

Therefore there is no solution.

Comment: Taking negative values into consideration?

Comment: @barakmanos yes. If $x$ is even $x^4, x^6$ are both even, and if $x$ is odd then $x^4$ and $x^6$ are odd. Sign is irrelevant.... Note that the solutions reduces to $x^4 \equiv x^6 \pmod{2}$ implies that $a^4+b^4+c^4 \equiv a^6+b^6+c^6 \pmod{2}$.

Comment: Is there any real solution exists?

Comment: And to prove that $x^4\equiv x^6 \pmod{2}$ it suffices to check the cases $x \equiv 0,1 \pmod{2}$. Or an overkill is to use the stronger form of Fermat Little Theorem: $$x^2 \equiv x \pmod{2} \Rightarrow x^6 \equiv x^2 \cdot x^2 \cdot x^2 \equiv x \cdot x \cdot x^2 \pmod{2}$$ Actually you can prove that $x^n \equiv x \pmod{2}$ for all $n \geq 2$.

Comment: @Argha If you are familiar with symmetric polynomials, they guarantee that complex solutions do exist, and you can find the cubic polynomial which has them as roots. Than you can decide if they are real or not....

Answer (score 6):

Note that $|n|\ge 3 \implies n^4\ge 81.$ Thus in the first equation it is $a,b,c\in\{0,\pm 1,\pm 2\}.$ It is easy to check that the solution is $a=0,b=\pm 2,c=\pm 2,$ or any permutation.

Now, $$a^5+b^5+c^5\le 0^5+2^5+2^5=64<186,$$ from where you can conclude that there is no solution.

Answer (score 2):

The lowest possible values for fourth powers of integers are $$0^4 = 0 \qquad 1^4 = (-1)^4 = 1 \qquad 2^4 = (-2)^4 = 16$$

By inspection, it becomes very clear that two of $a,b,c$ must have absolute value $2$, and one must be zero, in order for your first equation to hold.

Without loss of generality, suppose $c=0$ and $a = \pm b = \pm 2$.

Now $a^5 + b^5$ must be $2^5 + 2^5$, $-2^5 + 2^5$, or $-2^5 -2^5$. None of these is equal to $186$, so there are no solutions in the integers.

Answer (score 1):

Let $m = \max\{|a|,|b|,|c|\}$ then the first equation gives us$$m^4 \leq 32\to m\leq 32^{1/4}$$ and the third equation gives us $$803 = a^6+b^6+c^6 \leq 3\cdot m^6 \leq 3(32)^{6/4}$$

which is a contradiction since $3(32)^{6/4} \approx 543.06 < 803$ so there are no real solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a system of equations of the form
$$a^{n_1}+b^{n_1}+c^{n_1}=C_1$$
$$a^{n_2}+b^{n_2}+c^{n_2}=C_2$$
$$a^{n_3}+b^{n_3}+c^{n_3}=C_3$$
The first thing you should do is write the first equation as a function of one of the variables. Here, it could be
$$c=\sqrt[n_1]{C-a^{n_1}-b^{n_1}}$$
Substitute that into the second equation:
$$a^{n_2}+b^{n_2}+(\sqrt[n_1]{C-a^{n_1}-b^{n_1}})^{n_2}=C_2$$
Now do some algebra and try to write this equation as a function of $b$, insert that and the equation for $c$ into the last equation, and solve for $a$. You can then solve for $b$; knowing both, you can solve for $c$.

Comment: Can you show this "some algebra" and calculate the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Let $E_n=a^n+b^n$, then we have that $E_n=(a+b)E_{n-1}-abE_{n-2}$.
Given your problem, you can put c any value you want, and let n=6, then you will get an easy eqation were you can put one of the two, a or b, and from the equation you will get the other one for a certain c.

Comment: Can you calculate the solution?